# How do I use localhost as a "table of contents" directory?

Tags: .htaccess, directory, localhost, directory-structure, tableofcontents

My brother and I are using Dropbox as a means of sharing our website projects.  I put a small html page in the main folder that contains this:

```
<a href="project1/index.php">Project 1</a><br />
<a href="project2/index.html">Project 2</a><br />
<a href="project3/index.html">Project 3</a><br />
```

Using WAMP, I set localhost to this page so I can conveniently access all of our projects this way.  Here's my problem:

These links only work because the directory is specified.  Within these pages, the navigation links don't specify the directory, so it links to "localhost/about.php" rather than "localhost/project1/about.php".  Using "file:///C:/ ... " would not work, as WAMP would no longer run the php.

I wasn't sure how to search for solutions to this problem, since I don't know the technical name for a "table of contents" as I'm calling it.  After searching for variations of the issue, however, I think it may be possible to rig up something with htaccess.  Thanks for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Not really sure I understand what your are trying to achieve here...

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is move your dropbox. If i recall you can CHOOSE where your dropbox folder it. Put your drop box in C:\website that way it will sync your WAMP install. Have your bother do the same and then it should work.

Comment: Thanks Wolfkin, that's a solution I hadn't considered!  I moved my Dropbox as you said, but unfortunately it still does not work.  In fact, there's a rather peculiar problem:

The links work when I open the file directly, but they don't do anything when I use localhost.  Also, even if I open the file and click the link, php doesn't run.  I have to type "localhost/project1/index.php" for the php to run.

Comment: After changing my code back from "file:C:///dropbox/project1/index.php" to just "/project1/index.php", I'm back where I started.